# Atualização de Campos Utilizando Checkbox - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um formulário de Cadastro de Usuários, onde disponibilizo as opções de selecionar diversas opções em Checkbox.

Cadastro - Esportes que Pratica: Futebol, Volei, Natação e etc. (Os usuários podem selecionar vários).

Estou com problemas na atualização de registros, pois preciso mostrar os campos que podem ser preenchidos na atualização e marcar os escolhidos anteriormente.

No trecho abaixo apenas exibo os itens disponíveis. Preciso pegar o registro marcado na inserção e marcar como checked.

View

```
           @foreach ($esportesas $item)
              <label class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
               <input name="areas[]" value="{{ $item->id }}" type="checkbox">{{
                     ($item->area)
                   }}
               </label>
               @endforeach
              </label>
            @endforeach
```

Controller

```
 public function edit($id)
 {
     /* Dados Cadastrados */
     /* Aqui utilizo um relacionamento via Eloquent utilizo Foreach para fazer a Interação Ex: 

     foreach ($dados->esportes as $value) {
        var_dump($value->id)
     }

     */
    $dados = Usuarios::find($id);



     /* Lista de Esportes Cadastrados para Gerar View */
     $esportes = Esportes::all();

     return view('/edit', compact('dados', 'esportes'));

  }
```

Comment: Está correndo esse `@foreach`? Pois tem 2 `@endforeach`, isso é relacionado a um outro looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma que creio ser a mais fácil seria a utilização do [**Laravel Collective**](https://laravelcollective.com/) (porem ele está sendo reformulado temporariamente está fora)

Porem vamos na forma mais manual:

```
    @foreach ($esportesas $item)
    <label class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        @if (in_array($item->id, $arrayJaSalvoNoBanco))
            <input name="areas[]" value="{{ $item->id }}" type="checkbox" checked>
        @else
            <input name="areas[]" value="{{ $item->id }}" type="checkbox" >
        @endif
        {{($item->area)}}
    </label>
    @endforeach
</label>
@endforeach
```

Aqui estou utilizando o [`in_array();`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php) para verificar se o **id** do loop do **foreach** esta contido no array `$arrayJaSalvoNoBanco`.

Onde o `$arrayJaSalvoNoBanco` seria um array contendo os id's que já foram salvos no banco para esse **update** em questão.

**OBS.:** O `$arrayJaSalvoNoBanco`  é apenas um exemplo.

Testa ai e veja se funciona.

Comment: Olá Bulfaitelo,
Então no Array $esportes tenho apenas os valores tipo: Futebol, Volei e etc. Não consegui uma forma de jogar a opção escolhida no cadastro para essa tela. 

Consegui marcar a caixa de seleção utilizando outro foreach, mas os campos ficam duplicados.

Comment: No controller que você chama essa view, provavelmente você passa um id, faz a busca com base nesse id e pega os itens que ele já salvou retorna dentro a view e basicamente é isso.

Comment: Então até funciona isso, consigo pegar os valores que estão salvos no banco. Mas não encontrei uma forma de colocá-los nesse Foreach.

Comment: Atualiza a pergunta me mostrando como você pega esses dados e resultado obtido, assim da pra eu entender melhor seu ambiente

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, coloquei o Controller. 

Sobre o tópico anterior é somente um foreach mesmo. Estava realizando alguns testes.

Comment: Bulgaitelo, atualizei a pergunta.